# getting value of foreach from knockout js custom binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a foreach databind which has this basic information.

```
<div data-bind="foreach : info">
<p data-bind="$data.cash"></p>
<p data-bind="$data.orig_id"></p>
<input type="checkbox"  data-bind="bootstrapSwitchOn : $root.on_off"/>
</div>
```

Here is the Switch Code.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapSwitchOn = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $elem = $(element);
        $(element).bootstrapSwitch();
        $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())); // Set intial state
        $elem.on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
            valueAccessor()(data.value);
        }); // Update the model when changed.
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var vStatus = $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state');
        var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (vStatus != vmStatus) {    
$(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', vmStatus);
        }
    }
};
```

Which I got from here .https://jsfiddle.net/meno/MBLP9/
Normally it is that when there is checkbox, it returns back all the information like orig_id and cash in the js file,like if I do something like this

```
self.money = ko.observable();
this.clickHandler = function(item){
                    self.money(item.orig_id);
                    self.sendInfo() ;
                    }
<div data-bind="foreach : info">
            <p data-bind="$data.cash"></p>
            <p data-bind="$data.orig_id"></p>
            <input type="checkbox"  data-bind="click:$root.clickHandler"/> Click
        </div>
```

but I am not getting those values using this custom binding.
Is there any way where I can get the `orig_id` information when I click the checkbox and use it as inside an observable in the above example and also call a function called `self.sendInfo();`.

Comment: Have your tried the `text` binding? `<p data-bind="text: $data.cash"></p>`

Comment: @DaveB yea of course, but the main thing is that I need the information of each array to go to the custom binding and should give me the information from the array

Comment: Have you tried using the `viewModel` parameter in your binding? Try using `console.log(viewModel.orig_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

please try the following, i used another directive,

**Binding Handler**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapSwitchOn = {
                    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
                        var observable = valueAccessor();
                        console.log(observable);
                        $elem = $(element);
                        $(element).bootstrapSwitch();
                        $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())); // Set intial state
                        $elem.on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
                            /* added the two line */
                            var observable = valueAccessor();
                            allBindingsAccessor.get('callFunction').call(context, observable);
                        }); // Update the model when changed.
                    },
                    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                        var vStatus = $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state');
                        var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        if (vStatus != vmStatus) {
                            $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', vmStatus);
                        }
                    }
                };
```

**View Model**

```
$(function () {
    var vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.info = ko.observableArray([{cash: 1, orig_id: 'name1'}, {cash: 2, orig_id: 'name'}, {cash: 3, orig_id: 'name3'}]);
    self.money = ko.observable();
    this.clickHandler = function (item) {
      console.log(item);
    }
    self.sendInfo = function () {

    }
 };
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="foreach : info">
  <p data-bind="$data.cash"></p>
  <p data-bind="$data.orig_id"></p>
  <input type="checkbox"  class="mySwitch" data-bind="bootstrapSwitchOn : $data,callFunction:$root.clickHandler"/>
</div>
```

please note i sued another directive Call function and then called that from binding handler.

Let me know if that works in your case.